# Is there a way to convert x,y coordinates to a grayscale matrix? (python)

Tags: python, matrix, grayscale

For example if I have an 2xN matrix where the first row are my x values and the second row are my y values, can I convert these points to a grayscale matrix? Is there such thing?

ie)

```
X = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]
```

Comment: What do you mean by grayscale matrix?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert into a grayscale image

```
import numpy as np

X = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

a=np.array(X)
grayscale=(a-np.amin(a))/(np.amax(a)-np.amin(a))

print(grayscale) # or do want ever you want

#if want to view the image
import cv2

cv2.imshow("grayscale", grayscale)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```